# Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on null in on line 33

Tags: php, debugging, pdo

Below is the sample of the code im working
im getting a fatal error on line 33 please help me if you can thank you very much

```
     private $dbh;
     private $error;
     private $stmt;

    public function __construct() {
         //  set DSN
        $dsn = 'mysql:host=' . $this->host . ';dbname=' . $this->dbname;
         // set options
         $options = array (
              PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true,
              PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
         );
         //  create a new PDO instance
        try {
        $this->dbh = new PDO ($dsn, $this->user, $this->pass, $options);
        }
        //  catch any errors

         catch(PDOException $e){
            $this->error = $e->getMessage();
         }
    }

    public function query($query) {
       $this-> stmt = $this-> dbh->prepare($query); 
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using exceptions wrong way.

Just make your code like this

```
public function __construct() {
    $dsn = 'mysql:host=' . $this->host . ';dbname=' . $this->dbname;
    $options = array (
          PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true,
          PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
    );
    $this->dbh = new PDO ($dsn, $this->user, $this->pass, $options);
}

public static function __call($method, $args)
{
    return call_user_func_array(array($this->dbh, $method), $args);
}

public static function run($sql, $args = [])
{
    $stmt = $this->dbh->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute($args);
    return $stmt;
}
```

this is ALL the code you may ever need for your  wrapper. All other code will be erroneous and superfluous.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be that even though you are catching the error you are still going ahead to run the query function, therefore, if the construct did fail then $dbh would have never been initialised.